# How do I remove a newly created element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

**Html**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Go</button>
   
    <button onclick="removeone()">
        Remove
    </button>
```

**Javascript**

This lets me go to any website in an iframe window

```
        function myFunction() {
            let userdata= prompt("Enter site name", "http://");
            if (userdata != null) {
                const ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
                ifrm.setAttribute("src", userdata);
                ifrm.style.width = "1620px";
                ifrm.style.height = "880px";
                document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
            } else {}
            }
```

This removes the iFrame

```
            function removeone() {
                const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe')
                iframe.remove()`
```

My problem is whenever I remove the iframe, it removes the oldest element first, and not the newly created one as I want it to.
I'm new to programming in JavaScript.

Comment: Down vote because the code could easily save a reference to the iframe that it created and then latter remove it.   That would be much simpler and more dependable than the selected answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Bind "click" event to <button>
document.querySelector(".open").onclick = openIframe;

// Event handler passes event object by default
function openIframe(event) {
  // Prompt user for url
  let url = prompt("Enter site name", "https://");
  // If url isn't null...
  if (url != null) {
    // Create <iframe> and <button>
    const ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    const btn = document.createElement("button");
    // Add attributes and styles to both elements
    ifrm.src = url;
    ifrm.style.display = "block";
    ifrm.style.width = "98%";
    ifrm.style.minHeight = "100vh";
    btn.style.display = "block";
    btn.textContent = "Remove";
    // Append <button> then <iframe> to <body>
    document.body.append(btn, ifrm);
    // Bind "click" event to <button>
    btn.onclick = function(event) {
      // Find the element that follows <button> (ie <iframe>) and remove it
      this.nextElementSibling.remove();
      // <button> removes itself
      this.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="open">GO!</button>
```

Comment: is it possible to implement a button that goes forward and backwards within the iframe page history, and not the parent tab? I tried but it gave me an error, something to do with CORS

Comment: It's probably because iframes are severely limited when it's `src` is to a domain other than the one the webpage belongs to. If you happen to have editing privileges for the site inside the iframe then you'll most likely have more access through it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
function removeone() {
    const n = document.querySelectorAll('iframe').length;
    const iframe = document.querySelectorAll('iframe')[n-1];
    iframe.remove();
}
```

### Explanation

From the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

so instead, you can use `querySelectorAll`.
Also from the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

> The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors

so you simply grab the last element of that NodeList and remove it. You can get the last element in a NodeList just like you would in a regular array in Javascript.